# SQL How to SELECT python variable in SQL

Tags: python, sql

Tried something like this
cur.execute('SELECT ? FROM translations WHERE imagename = ? ', (target, filename,))

but it just returned [('de',), ('de',), ('de',), ('de',), ('de',), ('de',)]

being target = 'de'

Comment: You _can't_ use `?` placeholders for the column and table names in your prepared statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: How many different possible values of `target` do you expect?

Comment: 3 at the moment, one for each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* use `?` for database object names, such as table and column names.  Allowing this would represent a big security risk.  One workaround here would be to just maintain separate statements for each logic flow, e.g.

```
if target == "col1":
    cur.execute('SELECT col1 FROM translations WHERE imagename = ?', (filename,))
elif target == "col2":
    cur.execute('SELECT col2 FROM translations WHERE imagename = ?', (filename,))
else:
    cur.execute('SELECT col3 FROM translations WHERE imagename = ?', (filename,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the whole row(s) via SQL, and then grab the relevant values from the result. Something like:

```
result = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM translations WHERE imagename = ?', (filename,))
texts = [row[target] for row in result.fetchall()]
```

Comment: This solution requires selecting _every_ column, including all N-1 which are not even needed.  In general, `SELECT *` is bad practice.

Comment: We can narrow it down to the whitelist of allowed column names, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Since [parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) were defined to pass values of data, you will have to handle this in your program. You can fetch all the columns and process it in-memory

[UPDATE]

Pointing to the solutions specified above